# PHP POSTing is not sending form data to action page

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm really struggling to get my .php page to successfully post data to the next php page. Everywhere I look, it seems as though I am doing exactly what they suggest, so I am completely lost as to why my code is not working.

Index.php

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <ol>
        <li>What is your gender?
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
                    <input type="radio" class="space" name="gender" value="female">Female
                    <input type="radio" class="space" name="gender" value="other">Other
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

submit.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Thank you!</h1>
        <p><?php echo $_POST["gender"]; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a much more shortened version of what I have, but when I enter values into the form and hit 'Submit', it DOES direct to the other PHP page, but I'm not able to access any of the form values.

Comment: do you have any other forms on the page?  In other words your not nesting forms right?

Comment: Is PHP enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. It does not work because you need a server to run PHP locally. You need a **server** to handle HTTP requests and PHP installed on your PC to work local.

There is a complete solution called [AMPPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPPS).
AMPPS installs [Apache Server](https://httpd.apache.org/), PHP, MySQL and more.

When you install and run AMPPS, the server starts. Now you need to create a folder in this direction to place your project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www
```

Now place both index.php and submit.php to the folder you created.
So if you named your folder, for example, "**mysite**",  you can go to your website using this url in your browser:

```
http://localhost/mysite/
```

All done. You are ready to code.

In case you need a database, you can go to this link to use phpMyAdmin and of course you should write some PHP code to connect database:

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes total sense.